# Clear Coat, would this be able to be buffed out?

Tags: paint-clearcoat

[image]

Would this be able to be buffed out? The clear coat has a stain

Comment: Can't tell much from the photo but this looks to be more than a "buff out" problem.  Take it to a body shop and get their take on it

Comment: Here is some more information. I was able to get all the black stuff off, but the brown on the clear coat still remains. Almost as if it has 'stained' the clear coat? Thank you, I will inquire with a body shop tomorrow

Comment: Tell us how it happened.  Presumably this is not freshly sprayed clear-coat?

Comment: Can you tell us if you have any idea what the staining substance is? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the stain is tar, try a gentle rub on a small area with a solvent such as lighter fuel on a tissue, which shouldn't affect the paint.